# Why is there an edit link for answers from other people?

Tags: discussion, answers, edits, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can any user edit any other user’s question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120576/why-can-any-user-edit-any-other-users-question-or-answer)

I just asked a question and I was going to comment on one of the answers.  Instead, I accidentally hit edit and I was able to change the person's answer.  I did not hit save, so I don't know if it would have saved it, but I just noticed it had the edit to begin with.  Can you really save over other people's answers?

Answer (score 5):

This is addressed in [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> Like Wikipedia, this site is
>   collaboratively edited. If you are not
>   comfortable with the idea of your
>   questions and answers being edited by
>   other trusted users, this may not be
>   the site for you.

Comment: It's amazing that a user can get to 2000 rep without realizing that people can edit other people's posts.

Comment: It wouldn't be so hard for those users who amass all their rep points by asking **lots** of questions but don't really participate in the community at all.

Comment: remember, the edit threshold is only 100 now for CW questions.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you got edit ability when you just hit 2000 rep.