# Any qualms slashing the slow wind-up?

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

Many questions begin with an absurdly slow wind-up (and end with a wind-down).  You know the kind I mean.  Something like this:

> Hello.  I am new to [***some technology***].  I have been trying to
> figure out something.  I have looked at many sources on the internet
> trying to solve this without success.  Please help me.  Is there a
> solution to my problem?  Do you have the solution to my problem?  I am
> using [***some technology unrelated to the problem***] as well as
> [***some other technology unrelated to the problem***].
>
> [**The actual question**]
>
> Thank you.  If you have a solution to my problem please let me know.  I need help for this problem ASAP.

This drives me crazy and, in my view, makes the site less usable when left unedited.  I'd prefer to just strike it all out.  BUT, when editing, the instructions for editing don't really provide any authority for striking this.  Here are the editing guidelines:

> ► fix grammatical or spelling errors
>
> ► clarify meaning without changing it
>
> ► correct minor mistakes
>
> ► add related resources or links
>
> ► always respect the original author

The last one (i.e., respect) might even be construed as an instruction not to crop excess language.  Can/do we agree that editing out this sort of language is appropriate and, if so, can something be added to the editing instructions allowing for and encouraging it?

**UPDATE**: I agree [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135619/is-it-correct-to-edit-question-to-remove-verbose-introduction?lq=1) is a related question, but the remaining question, which is really a feature-request, is the following:

- In light of the seeming agreement in the other thread, can we add an item to the "How to Edit" bulleted list to the effect:  "Remove unnecessary verbosity."

Comment: Regarding the respect bit, some authors can get picky about this; i.e. they actually want to have a more elaborate question and they will engage in rollback wars to preserve it :)

Comment: "Respect" isn't *code* for anything here. It means just what it says: when you're editing someone else's post, show them respect. Do your best to make them look good and help them get useful answers, but also recognize that it's *their* name that's permanently attached to the post; if they *insist* on a particular style, respect their wishes and move on. Also note that some *readers* get pretty hung up on even superfluous context, so while putting it at the start of the post ain't great, removing it entirely can end up hurting the asker.

Comment: I aggressively prune such intros.

Comment: @meagar Your comment makes me picture this activity: http://istenbizony.hu/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Chain-Linked-Chainsaw-Gif-Chain-Linked-Chainsaw.gif

Comment: @J.Steen All images should be that image.