# Why do we allow multiple peer edits for a given question?

Tags: discussion, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can any user edit any other user's question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120576/why-can-any-user-edit-any-other-users-question-or-answer)

If the person asking the question wants to edit the details of the question that's fair. But I am wondering why editors get to change the question?

Secondly, it seems like multiple peer edits are also allowed? So your question ends up being not what you intended to be at the end of edits.

Comment: my question is specifically for editing privileges for someone else's question ..

Comment: From the other question: "how come any user can change any other user's question or answer?".

Comment: Also of interest, the site [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing), which presents the same information in a more succinct format: "*...this site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. If you see something that needs improvement, click edit and help us make it so! [...] If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.*"

Comment: "ends up being not what you intended to be at the end of edits"... if an edit changes the meaning of the question it can be rolled back. Edits should improve the question, not change the meaning.