# Failed a Reopen Question audit — sure looks like "Not a real question" to me

Tags: support, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [this audit here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen#reopen/1563510?&_suid=1361383938828033884321669261047), which was shown as being closed as "Not a real question".

Seeing as the vote count was positive, I figured it was an audit, but I selected "Leave Closed" anyways because to me

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here.  This question is ambiguous, vague...

There's no code examples, and the phrasing is clunky at best.

This is my second failed audit in two days for difficult questions (first failed audit is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1555802#./1555802?&_suid=136138530646804532740567496166), also now closed), so if I get temporarily suspended, it won't be the end of the world (I'll think of it as a forced vacation).

That said, is there a way to dispute these audits?  Or is posting the audit here sufficient?

Comment: That question [has never been closed](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14873411/revisions) up to now, so something's wonky here. (It should be closed very shortly, however, because it's awful.)

Comment: That question looks off-topic to me.

Comment: I really hate that feeling when you know you're on an audit, know the answer it is expecting, and know that it's wrong.  It puts you in the position of either doing the wrong action to pass the audit or doing what's right and failing.

Comment: Jeez. Audits are getting worse.

Comment: @Servy What about skipping?

Comment: @JoshCaswell - yeah, I was *really* surprised that question had a vote count of +6 when I reviewed it. And now it's closed for real :)

Comment: @ughoavgfhw That's probably the best of the possible options, but it still shouldn't be happening to begin with.  Automatically generated audits are just inherently broken since the mechanisms the system relies on aren't 100% perfect, or aren't very clear.  They should honestly all be fabricated by trustworthy people (i.e. mods) so that the "correct" answer is actually correct, and so that ambiguous cases are avoided entirely.

Comment: I _was_ temporarily suspended after my last meta audit related question ;). A lot of my failures ended up as bug/support questions on meta... It's been a little weird bit being able to click review constantly but it's given me more spare time :).

Comment: I've asked for a button "suggest as honeypot" to be available to "good reviewers" - it's kind of buried right now in a question about there not being edit audits - should I ask it again as a feature request?

Comment: The question had 6 upvotes, so it must be good! A similar problem reported here [How do we select audits for Reopen review?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167239/how-do-we-select-audits-for-reopen-review).

Comment: @KateGregory: That's a good suggestion.  I suspect SE is trying to come up with an algorithm to automate this, though. The problem with automation in general is that a machine can't divine meaning, and therefore might not be the best arbiter of human judgement.

Comment: @KateGregory - by all means; in fact, I think I upvoted you last time as well.

Comment: This is slightly off-topic, but the edit performed on the question in question is completely and utterly idiotic. What's the point of adding all those line breaks? Argh!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168374/bring-a-human-factor-into-review-audit-composition-selection is the feature request

Comment: Press reopen to pass the audit then go to the question and vote to close

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Posting here is sufficient.

Right now, these audit questions are selected using the following criteria:

- Recently asked
- Score between 5 and 15 (inclusive)
- Never locked, migrated, or deleted
- No close votes or downvotes, ever (only for close/reopen audits)
- (On Stack Overflow) at least 100 views

The biggest weakness here is the Score criteria. If you ask a question and five of your friends up-vote it, you're in the running - not saying that's what happened *here*, but it's definitely been a problem.

While Kate's suggestion for hand-picked audits would be nice, that really can't scale; we need a lot of these generated on a regular basis.

Comment: Two questions spring to mind:  **(1)**  If I come across a question like this, and I skip the audit, will anyone else get it?  **(2)** If the answer is "Yes" to question 1, what happens if I downvote and/or vote-to-close the question?  Will someone else still get it, or will the negative votes remove it as an audit?

Comment: Why wouldn't you pick questions that had actually been reopened to audit reopen reviews? Not enough of those?

Comment: That should disqualify it from being used in future audits, @LittleBobbyTables

Comment: @Josh: well, the intention here (and with most audits) is to pick "known good" posts - examples that are *clearly* good or bad. If a post has been re-opened, that still means at least someone thought it should've been closed at one time. Picking closed->edited->reopened posts might improve this, but...

Comment: @Shog9 is number of question views taken into account in selection?

Comment: @gnat: no; that's not a bad idea - there have been a small number of audits with < 60 views that've had more than their fair share of failures. Above that, it doesn't look like it'd make much difference.

Comment: Would choosing questions that have had close votes, not been closed, and actually been judged as suitable to leave open be better candidates for this?  Then we know that 'critcal eyes' have passed over the question.  Relying primarily on votes is bound to lead to some - errr - questionable items being used as audit fodder.

Comment: @gnat: FWIW, we implemented your suggestion and now require at least 100 views on a question in order for it to be considered for a "known good" close/reopen audit on Stack Overflow.  I'm reasonably happy with the results of this so far.

Comment: @Shog9 I see. 100 views make good sense at SO (and probably at SF/SU as well). What amount views would you consider for smaller sites? With less traffic there, amount of "audit item candidates" with 100+ views might be quite small.

Comment: The pools are already very small on sites that aren't SO (to the extent enabling audits at all on most smaller sites isn't really feasible). Should be fewer weird outliers though too. @gnat

Comment: understood. "fewer weird outliers" makes sense to me, thanks for explaining @Shog9

Comment: I'd like an "I disagree with this ruling" button... but I can see that being abused rather swiftly ;)

Comment: I recently failed a close-vote audit because I'd written a comment outlining that the multiple questions should be split into individual questions, and that I was only voting to close *this* multi-headed hydra-question.

Comment: Either your answer or [animuson's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222122/155074) is incorrect: "t's a bad audit. There were three close votes for that off-topic reason that had previously expired on that question. It just didn't get enough attention."

Comment: Different queue, different rules for audits, @Łukasz웃Lツ

Comment: **"No close votes or downvotes, ever"** -- is this only for Reopen queue audits / only for some sites? I ask because at some queues / sites this doesn't seem to be the case, see [Post I voted down and close is shown to me as known good audit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203663/post-i-voted-down-and-close-is-shown-to-me-as-known-good-audit)

Comment: Only for close/reopen audits, @gnat.

Comment: *"that really can't scale; we need a lot of these generated on a regular basis..."* - Rather than serve 1 question per person being audited, use the same question for 5 or 6 different reviewers. The 5 or 6 different reviewers should all (or nearly all) arrive at the same result. If they don't, then it may not be a good audit question. If its not a good audit question, then have the system double down vote it (or double up vote it) to remove the question or answer from potential audits. The double voting leaves the score unchanged.

Comment: @Shog9 "No close votes or downvotes, ever" rule seems to be broken in this audit: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/review/close/74382 - it presents a closed question with 5 close votes as known good

Comment: Seems to be an issue with caching, @gnat - looking into this.

Comment: thanks! BTW Glen has opened "official bug report" for this issue: [Review Audit Fail - closed question served as known good in reopen queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234030/165773)

Comment: Shog, even though FP audits have weaker requirements, using post with **three** votes down as "known good" ([example discussed here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280019/839601)) doesn't feel right, does it?

Comment: That actually made a surprisingly good audit, @gnat. Although I can't exactly give credit to the selection algorithm for that.