# I don't get why I failed this review test

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I got this as a review task:

[Scanner not working instead of buffered reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898499/scanner-not-working-instead-of-buffered-reader)

I read the post, added a comment that I thought would help clarify, and voted to leave open.  However, it should have been obvious to me that it clearly should have been closed.

What should have tipped me off?

I don't make it a habit of rushing through these tasks (I think I've missed one or two otherwise) and I know that this kind of thing is subjective, but the tests should be obviously one way or the other, and I don't feel this one was.

Comment: "Fix my code" questions aren't usually welcome on SO, but I agree, this audit test really should have been more of a "slam dunk", obvious piece of crap.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177700/how-is-this-a-failed-audit

Answer (score 6):

It's not about what would have tipped you off - I would expect most people to fail the occasional audit - especially due to the somewhat controversial quality of some of the questions that are automatically chosen as review candidates.

I would have voted to close that question because:

- it's just a block of code with a *"please tell me what's wrong with this code"* question
- there is no explanation of exactly *how* it's not working

While it is potentially answerable, it's still not a good quality question and shouldn't be encouraged in its current state.

Comment: Sorry for mis-spellings - I'm typing on a keyboard with no 'h' or 'j' so have to copy/paste them in :)

Comment: Wow - and I thought **I** had it bad working with a keyboard with a sticky `5` key on the number pad :)

Comment: @Slugster: You don't have a #1 fan, do you?  Someone that is forcing you to finish that final piece of code in the series with a broken keyboard?  :)

Comment: @john Nah, I'm just on holiday and the laptop has some dodgy keys, I can live without the j but the h is reasonably common. I might have to memories their ISO codes so I can avoid copy/paste :)