# Vote to close question with no research effort - failed audit

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Audit in question is this: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3217410

I disagree with the audit although there are five upvotes, no flags, and no close votes.

Even though the asker demonstrated a minimum understanding of the problem, all I get from the question is that he/she knows about htaccess. There is no attempted solution or anything else in the question that demonstrates the asker researched how to use htaccess on Apache, or any other methods to solve the problem.

I know that this question isn't horribly bad (which makes it a bad candidate for review audits), but in my opinion I still would have voted to close and probably left a comment on the question on how to improve it.

Another thing is that initially I was banned for 7 days, but now I see that the ban lasts until Nov 27, an entire month. How did this happen?

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174118/the-time-of-automatic-review-bans-should-be-increased-with-every-new-ban) question might explain why the ban period has been increased.

Comment: After failing first audits I became a bit overzealous too. Questions like that make the audit very tricky. Especially if you just want to leave a comment - that is hardly robo-reviewing.

Comment: Related: [How is this a failed audit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177700/how-is-this-a-failed-audit) [What an audit!? Would you fail?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197632/what-an-audit-would-you-fail)