# Close vote review failed

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Today, I failed the following review audit in the "Close Votes" queue:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2574688

From the question:

> I'm building a project on phonegap using JQuery mobile.
>
> What is the best architecture to build it, something like MVC but without Server side, I want to use local storage inside the mobile.
>
> I would appreciate providing me with architecture and simple sample code that works on that.

If the OP asked "how can I use local storage with PhoneGap and jQuery", that would IMO be a valid question.
But the OP is specifically asking "what is the best architecture". He then goes on to ask for an actual code sample. Together, I feel this means the question should be closed, either as "too broad" or "primarily opinion-based".

Was I being too harsh, to want to close this question?
Or is this a bad review audit?

Comment: It is a **terrible** review audit. I've voted to close that question.

Comment: Same problem as [this guy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168777/was-this-question-a-suitable-review-queue-audit-test). I think Shog is onto something: 5 votes is far too low a bar for Stack Overflow. There are lots of terrible questions that inexplicably get 3-5 votes. And of course, [no matter what score we pick, people might still fail the audit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190106/dealing-with-find-out-whos-going-to-buy-the-croissants).

Comment: (Totally as an aside: why the explicit line breaks in some of the paragraphs? I'm tempted to edit them out.)

Comment: +1 Agree with you :) voted to close also

Comment: Closed. (7 more to go).

Comment: @Arjan Matter of taste... I for one like short, separated paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks all, glad to see this question is now On Hold.

Comment: Just for your information: if you think the line breaks *separates* sections of text, then note that [they cannot always be seen](http://i.stack.imgur.com/i3yza.png). Also, a line break by itself [does not start a new paragraph](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines/45635#45635)?