# Faulty Reopen Question Audit

Tags: support, review, closed-questions, review-audits

Much like [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168366/failed-a-reopen-question-audit-sure-looks-like-not-a-real-question-to-me)

I have failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1649378) that I do not believe it is correct, This question does not have code to back up its complex question, and there are no answers that agree on a specific method or problem, (ie: it is either not constructive, or not a real question).

I am following the instruction of Shog9 from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168372/192545) stating that I should post it here.

Comment: hm how this question was picked for audit? having mere **80+** views doesn't feel like enough to reliably judge its contents

Comment: The question is fine and quite understandable to whomever would have worked with circular buffers before.  The answers are good and address the OP's problem.  You failed this audit for the right reasons.

Comment: @UphillLuge Well, I'm sorry but in my book when someone asks a question about how to implement something and/or is having trouble doing so, they should provide the code that they attempted, many, many questions have been closed because OP's do not include their code, and otherwise the question is probably salvageable, but will only ever be someone doing the work for the OP unless it can be seen that the OP has tried something.