# Am I wrong in thinking this review audit is incorrect?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I am of the opinion that [such a question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1710172) doesn't fit the Q&A format. From reading the FAQ, I thought it qualified as a chatty, open-ended question. Based on the answers in the question, it was certainly subjective and solicited debate, which is precisely the close reason in this test. I just don't understand why it was invalid to think it should remain closed and not reopened.

Perhaps this is a boundary case because the asker and answerers all have very high rep, or there isn't good coverage of the topic elsewhere on the internet, but I think it's brutal to be used as an review audit.

Comment: For what it's worth, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168372/148949) is a listing of the criteria used for picking review audit questions. Basically it became an audit candidate because it had a score range between 5-15, was never downvoted, and never closed. I don't think the question is constructive either, but some tags seem to be more forgiving of questions than others.

Comment: I would have taken the same action if I didn't visit the question, but I would have noticed that the question doesn't have any Reopen(x) if I did visit.

Comment: Aah, didn't realize there was no human role in coming up with these (although I was starting to suspect as much). Good trick AbZy! I'll remember that.

Comment: I'd prefer to hear the opinion of someone who actually works with Haskell whether the question is worth left opened or not. The question really is a bit open-ended (the part where it requests for example), but the rest asks for difference between 2 concepts in the language.

Comment: +1: I failed [the same one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1695312), for the same reason.

Answer (score 6):

I would have reviewed the same as you, based on the content. The reason you 'failed' is because the question was not closed to begin with. I am very gun shy about reopen reviews, and usually view the post itself before voting.

Comment: You're not really "voting" anymore, now are you? :P

Comment: @gnat Thanks for editing my fat-fingered typo, and the congrats!

Comment: @madara As an Evil Overlord, I vote early and often ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber, in case you don't get my flag, please realize that now your moderator vote completely invalidates the normal community close process requiring 5 votes.  Please use it with caution.  You can easily tell that that question is completely appropriate for Stack Overflow, it's a simple __specific__ question requiring a simple answer, and it's wrong to unilaterally close it.  Use your powers for good not evil.

Comment: @Lance I only voted when there were already a few votes (3).

Comment: Yes, I saw that, so it only took 4 to close.  I just wanted to make sure you understood your new powers.  There's a FR out there somewhere to give the mods the ability to cast a (1) close vote instead of their supervote (as they choose), but I don't think it got traction.

Comment: @Lance Thank you for your feedback

Comment: Here's the link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41062/add-a-way-for-moderators-to-cast-a-normal-non-binding-vote

Comment: @Lance - you seriously believe that Andrew has already started casting close votes without understanding his new moderator abilities?  That's kind of insulting to insinuate that, IMHO.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, actually if you go to the link in the last comment you'll see where a few different mods have stated that possible problem.  Do you really believe all people have perfect knowledge?

Answer (score -2):

I think it's a good basic specific question, and has some good answers.  It doesn't seem like a chatty question to me.

Comment: The problem is that in the review queue we are asked "This question has been closed. Would you like to reopen it?". Often the answer is "No thanks", even though the question for some reason  hasn't really been closed.