# Yet another poor question as a reopen honeypot

Tags: bug, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

[How to unit test views in ember.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903273/how-to-unit-test-views-in-ember-js)

1. code not in question
2. request for vague best practice
3. a bunch of verbiage about where the op works and what they do

In short, "How can I write unit tests in technology X" is not good question, and demanding that I vote to reopen it is wrong.

@Asad: one big improvement would be just add the occasionally-mentioned 'appeal' button. I don't even care if it does anything. I just find it extremely provocative to have the UI demand that, like Galileo, I swear that the earth isn't in fact moving.

My other suggestion is to restrict the audit questions to things that have, in fact, been *reopened*.

Comment: I definitely agree.

Comment: You mean as an audit you failed on?

Comment: Audit selection is automated, based on [these criteria](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168372/200500). Ideas on how to improve these criteria to filter out pointless question honeypots like this one are welcome.

Comment: Some part of the question can be edited - at least point 1 and 3 can be fixed.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha yes that's what happened.

Comment: I totally agree with only using questions that have actually been reopened. In fact, Shog mentioned the possibility of only using questions that have been closed->edited->reopened as honeypots in [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168366/failed-a-reopen-question-audit-sure-looks-like-not-a-real-question-to-me/168372#comment496066_168372) on the answer I linked. I think that would improve the situation, though obviously it is still possible to disagree with a reopening.

Comment: I have edited the question to remove the point 1 and 3. I am not sure about point 2 in this case.

Comment: @nhahtdh True, but the question did not deserve to be reopened in the state it was in. It is much better since your edit though, which addresses point 1.