# Who audits the audit reviews?

Tags: support, review, review-audits, vote-to-reopen

I just failed an audit by not voting to reopen this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615127/storing-and-comparing-against-objects-from-a-database).

But, IMHO, it's a poor fit for SO and *should* be closed. I wouldn't hesitate to close it if I stumbled upon it as "off topic" or maybe even "not constructive". At the very least it's debatable, so it shouldn't be a review audit - it's too close to definitively call.

Is there any checking done to ensure currently-open questions that are offered as audits *should* in fact be open?

Comment: Would you mind telling us why it should be closed in your opinion? Honestly in the extreme cases you fail an Audit and you don't think it's justified, a meta question is in order imho. It just seems so small in volume to justify any coding work.

Comment: I believe it should be closed because its too high level a question and covers too many moving parts. He's basically asking "how should I write this portion of my app". It's not a "code" question, but more a "pattern" type question. Perhaps programmers.SE might have been a better forum for it

Comment: The question in question has been viewed 154 times, it's open and upvoted, and has two upvoted answers. The community has already reviewed it and decided it's good enough for the site. Of course, the community doesn't always get it right, but is there _really_ a need for yet another review for every question picked as an audit? Neither reviewing nor auditing is perfect, and they'll never be.

Comment: Im not saying it's a bad question. I just think it's off topic

Comment: How is it off-topic?

Comment: I'm not really hep to Android dev, but I don't see the problem here either. FWIW, you can find the criteria we use for selecting these audit questions here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168366/failed-a-reopen-question-audit-sure-looks-like-not-a-real-question-to-me/168372#168372

Comment: It's not constructive, not even close. "What is the best way to do persistence on Android"? Really?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it's more "not constructive" on SO, but should be migrated somewhere else like programmers (that's what I meant by "off topic"). It's too broad - there are lots of ways to answer it, and which way is "best" is a matter of opinion, which could lead to debate, etc

Comment: An audit which garners a higher-than-average number of audit failures could indicate a poor audit question; is this tracked, with the worst offenders reviewed?

Answer (score 6):

Ultimately, Meta does.

You make a post here, complaining loudly about the audit. If you are in the wrong, someone will gently (I hope) tell you why.

If the audit is in the wrong, just go to the post in question and downvote or vote to close - Shog9 says that will do the trick.

Comment: Nope, we mods can't do anything about audits. They are automatically selected.

Comment: @mad Besides, if it you could nuke them, can you imagine the whining that would go on here...

Comment: @mad Huh. I was sure I read that somewhere.

Comment: *Tons* of people have the ability to prevent a question from being used as an audit. A single down-vote or close vote will do the job.

Comment: @Shog Really! Neat. What if it's a close vote audit where you were supposed to close?

Comment: Then the rules are a bit different, @Undo. You'd up-vote or reopen-vote to disqualify it.

Comment: @Shog That makes sense. Just do the opposite of what the audit wants in real life.

Comment: But what to do if the question is already closed? Similar just happened to me:  
I got this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19580228/85421) flagged to be closed. After reviewing the whole post in a second tab and seeing that it was **already closed** (since October 25th), I just clicked that no further action was needed - is that really a fail???

Comment: @Shog9: Thanks, that's good to know. Looks like I did the right thing with [this audit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/3723383), then. Maybe that should be added to [the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)?