# Audit is too obvious because button offers to "Recommend..." a vote

Tags: bug, review-audits, low-quality-posts, wording

I just encountered the following question in SuperUser's VLQ review queue, which made the audit pathetically obvious because I haven't *Recommended* close votes for a long time:

[image]

As a reviewer who appreciates audits that require me to [pay attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221177/271445), I found this way too obvious.

Can we have review audits drop the `Recommend` text when the user has the necessary rep to directly cast the appropriate vote?