# Request for review: close/reopen "known good" audits

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close, review-audits

The difficulty of some review audits in the /close and /reopen queues has been brought up here a few times recently. It's true: a few of these audits are *difficult*, if not outright misleading. We've tweaked [the criteria for choosing them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168366/failed-a-reopen-question-audit-sure-looks-like-not-a-real-question-to-me/168372#168372) a few times now, and I'm *reasonably* happy with the results - but there've been some interesting suggestions for improvement too, and rather than trust my gut on this I'd like to make this a bit more democratic.

I'm providing links to 3 different sets of questions. Each represents a different strategy for choosing "known good" audits suitable for the close and reopen review queues - that is, questions which should *not* be closed.

Please review the questions in each set and vote for the set(s) you think are suitable. Down-vote the sets you think are unsuitable, and if you find a particularly poor example, post it in a comment under the corresponding set.

I won't mention the criteria used for each set at this point, in hopes of making this *somewhat* objective - but you can probably figure some of it out if you're paying attention. Just try to focus on the suitability of the questions themselves.

(Note that there is some overlap between these sets, since they were pulled from the same time period)

Comment: Could you generate similar sets for ServerFault and post it on the meta there?

Comment: Just for clarification, all answers in the examples are considered for not to close/migrate, since I'd see some migrate candidates?

Comment: Depending on the results of this review, I'll expand round 2 to other sites, @ward. The hardest part of this is choosing criteria that produce enough results, and this gets a lot harder on smaller sites.

Comment: All of these examples expect a "leave open" or "edit" response,  @bummi

Comment: Why are you unwilling, apparently, to consider the obvious criteria for reopen audits -- that the question was *actually reopened*?

Comment: Because there are so very few of those, @ros. Ridiculously few. "Didn't I just get this review?" few.

Comment: @Shog9 In that case, is there any chance, on the other hand, of convincing you to implement the appeal button? We all know that the audits can't be perfect. But the 'failure' wording is strong to the point of giving offense to many. An appeal button might actually give you useful information, and would soften the offense.

Answer (score 7):

#### Known-good audit questions: strategy #4554

- [In Python, variables inside if conditions hide the global scope even if they are not executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18647162)
- [Force a compile time error if std::move will result in an unintended copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18646874)
- [Why can't gotos in Lua jump out of functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18646289)
- [How to use the comparison in GHC.TypeLits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18646253)
- [Why is the last number (1) printed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18646003)
- [R data.table count panel data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18645097)
- [find out windows in side-by-side mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18644975)
- [What's the harm to install a "AnyCPU" program on a 64-bit Windows using a 32-bit MSI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18643244)
- [Is it better to use System.arraycopy(...) than a for loop for copying arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18638743)
- [How does the caller of a function know whether Return Value Optimization was used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18637804)
- [Avoid/warn self initialization of C++ members](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18635468)
- [See who deleted git tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18635023)
- [Why is [- subsetting (i.e. deletion) of columns not possible with names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18634223)
- [What does self comparable interface do in Collections Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18633408)
- [Arithmetic mean on a multidimensional array on R and MATLAB: drastic difference of performances](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18631165)
- [Oracle object dependency loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18630962)
- [Query performance optimization for dynamically joined columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18630448)
- [Operator precedence - Arithmetic and Conditional operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18628256)
- [How (e.g. in what order) does this code run and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18628074)
- [Are commas meant to be syntactically valid in Javascript if statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18627452)
- [Are there any differences between these two higher-order function definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18626080)

Answer (score 3):

#### Known-good audit questions: strategy #4559

- [In Python, variables inside if conditions hide the global scope even if they are not executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18647162)
- [Force a compile time error if std::move will result in an unintended copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18646874)
- [Pass pointer from C++ to Python /w boost python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18646694)
- [How to use the comparison in GHC.TypeLits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18646253)
- [R data.table count panel data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18645097)
- [Java Generics and overridding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18644688)
- [What's the harm to install a "AnyCPU" program on a 64-bit Windows using a 32-bit MSI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18643244)
- [Why am I receiving this StackOverflowException?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18640861)
- [How does the caller of a function know whether Return Value Optimization was used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18637804)
- [Setting an Excel cell value to a decimal in C#. Differences between .NET 2 and .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18636312)
- [Avoid/warn self initialization of C++ members](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18635468)
- [See who deleted git tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18635023)
- [Why is [- subsetting (i.e. deletion) of columns not possible with names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18634223)
- [Haskell list drives in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18633083)
- [Arithmetic mean on a multidimensional array on R and MATLAB: drastic difference of performances](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18631165)
- [Oracle object dependency loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18630962)
- [Query performance optimization for dynamically joined columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18630448)
- [proportionally increase/decrease the wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18629255)
- [How (e.g. in what order) does this code run and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18628074)
- [Haskell: Defining a proper interface for data types with many fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18627107)
- [Why are char[] and char* as typedefs different, but sometimes... not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18626126)

Answer (score -3):

#### Known-good audit questions: strategy #4555

- [How to catch AJAX requests in Webbrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18668098)
- [Bootstrap loader synchronization error MSP430F249](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18665355)
- [How to make the main content div fill height of screen with css](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18665171)
- [How can I compute the coordinates of an Equilateral Triangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18662073)
- [How to run code every time a new socket is created on my Linux machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18661231)
- [Generic interface with generic elements and constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18659096)
- [Zend Framework select where clause placeholder slows process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18657284)
- [Control specific background subprocess in Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18656892)
- [2 executable in a method in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18654401)
- [Clarification about Bit-field ordering semantics in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18652148)
- [Java - Modifying a class to compute total number of objects created](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18648986)
- [Working with DTO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18648548)
- [Why use !! to coerce a variable to boolean for use in a conditional expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18648179)
- [SQL Server 2008 R2 Express multi-part could not be bound](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18648065)
- [Program Freezes while creating new instance of array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18647778)
- [Detecting one or more inflection points in a simple numeric vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18647661)
- [C: How to convert a pointer (array element) to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18645878)
- [Strip protocol and subdomain from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18644051)
- [efficient way to handle multiple hash maps in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18642776)
- [Is possible to make inheritance in this xml using jaxb?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18639222)

Comment: This list looks as if it was just picked randomly... [How to make the main content div fill height of screen with css](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18665171) "Anyone knows the answer? Thx" really? someone upvoted this?

Comment: FWIW, none of these lists were picked *randomly*.