# Moderator's edit to a question potentially changed its meaning and rendered an existing answer nonsensical

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question

[Shog9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9)'s edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113019/why-is-my-ipad-mini-not-detecting-in-xcode-after-updating-it-to-ios-7) specified that the version of Xcode being used was Xcode 5. This wasn't previously detailed in the question, and as a result, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19113435/1709587) (which basically consists of "Upgrade to Xcode 5") had been rendered nonsensical.

The question is probably more useful in its current form, but if we're going to keep it that way, the now-irrelevant answer should probably be nuked.

I'm not sure whether Shog9 put in the version number to match the accepted answer, whether he put it in by error, or whether there were (now-deleted) comments by the question asker stating that he was using Xcode 5.

I wasn't sure whether the appropriate course of action was, so I thought I'd make a Meta post and see what others made of it.

Comment: You can always @ ask him

Comment: @RichardTingle Where? That only works in reply to a comment, right?

Comment: @Shog9 In case notifying you like this actually works, please check out this question.

Comment: No, any (successful) editor can be @ replied to on post they edited

Comment: @RichardTingle Aha. I didn't know that. I'll @-reply to him on the question, then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2322/notify-us-when-the-question-has-been-edited-after-posting-an-answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My edits were triggered by [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203186/yarafp-yet-another-review-audit-failed-post).

There are several previous questions on using previous versions of Xcode with iOS 7, to which the answers all boil down to "install Xcode 5". This question got the same response - *seven times*. 5 comments and 2 answers all helpfully informed the asker that an upgrade to Xcode 5 would solve his problem...

*One* answer provided information on resolving the problem if it still existed with Xcode 5 installed. And that was the accepted answer.

So we're left with a situation where the question is either a duplicate, or specific to Xcode 5. Given the evidence, I think the latter is a safer bet - so I edited the question to reflect this.

The comments have been cleaned up, and one of the answers was deleted by its author long ago. Leaving another answer for folks who *haven't* upgraded doesn't seem like a bad idea, so I've updated that answer with a link to an older question on the XCode 4 issue.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm slightly concerned that the Xcode 4 answer will unfairly get (reasonably) downvoted for not answering the question as currently written, though. Indeed, I was going to downvote it myself before noticing that the Xcode version was only specified by your edit.

Comment: I suppose we could further edit that answer to discourage this perception. Fixing the grammar wouldn't hurt either. Done!

Comment: Nice. I think that's everything taken care of.

Comment: The accepted answer was a guess about the Xcode version just as much as the other answers, but it happened to be a correct guess. It doesn't seem "unfair" that an answer predicated on an incorrect guess, and not really a useful solution to the problem, should be downvoted. In fact, it wouldn't be unreasonable for it to be _removed_ by its author. Shog, your edit certainly makes it more helpful, but it's now basically a link to another problem -- "if you got here by mistake, look over there".

Comment: Exactly, @Josh - the answer would serve primarily to cross-reference the topics.

Comment: ...which is usually a function we reserve for comments, but... /me shrugs.

Comment: I kinda hate comments for this. Most folks can't edit comments. Editing links into the question is also good though.

Answer (score 8):

Anyone who edits a question can be @replied to. So in the first instance the appropriate action to take if you have questions regarding an edit is to ask the editor.

See the [comment reply FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for more details