# Confused by audit failure

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4192913

This question was presented as possibly off-topic and when I agreed I got the "You failed" message.  The question is about navigating a Haskell site and AFAICT has nothing to do with programming.  It's a "This site isn't behaving the way I expect, why is that?"

Please enlighten me.  How does this question fit into the SO guidelines?

Comment: Computers are not humans.  You failed this audit because it was _incorrectly_ upvoted.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203186/yarafp-yet-another-review-audit-failed-post

Comment: You should (perhaps downvote) and vote to close it instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Please enlighten me. How does this question fit into the SO guidelines?

It doesn't, it looks like a bad audit question to me.

The audits are selected by an algorithm so there is some bad ones that due get selected.  The criteria are:

- Recently asked
- Score between 5 and 15 (inclusive)
- Never locked, migrated, or deleted
- No close votes or downvotes, ever
- (On Stack Overflow) at least 100 views

So the post needed to meet all of the above to get selected.  If you encounter one, if you downvote or vote to close the post, that will ensure it is never selected again because it won't meet the criterion in the 4th bullet.

Comment: It's been (1) downvoted, (2) voted-to-close, (3) flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: @devnull why was it necessary to flag for a mod?  I see nothing here the community can't handle itself.

Comment: Perhaps not.  [This is another real-time example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22112280/how-to-add-a-space-in-string-and-save-it-in-file-c-programming) of how the community _upvotes_.

Comment: @devnull ok, you may be right, but personally, I think the meta effect probably takes care of most problem questions that get brought up.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on how it works.  The chastising tone of the "failure" message could use some work, and probably an "I disagree" button for users with sufficient rep (10K?) as proposed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780)

Comment: @ExUmbris no one likes the tone of the message, but when you review posts enough, you'll fail enough audits (everyone does, even moderators), that you just gloss over the message.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'm adjusting to that now that I understand how the process works.  Some people have implied that failures can get you banned from reviewing.  I've only failed 5-6 times in a year... is that anywhere near the threshold?

Comment: @ExUmbris no clue as the exact criteria is not public info but probably depends on frequency of the failures, how many you pass, and which review queues you used regularly.