# Close vote audit incorrect

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close, review-audits

I was just going through the close votes and was confronted with this close vote audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4392357 ([JavaScript built-in class documentation serialized in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241014/javascript-built-in-class-documentation-serialized-in-json))

In my opinion, this falls under 'Off topic, recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource':

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

As this question is clearly asking for a library (or off-site resource).

Comment: Downvote the question and you (no-one) won't see it again in the audit queue!

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223693/confused-by-audit-failure

Comment: @devnull Thanks, for some reason I expected these audits to be curated by humans ;)