# Would you fail this close votes audit?

Tags: support, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I believe that [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3053455) is a bad audit. (hm, for some reason it now says someone else reviewed and passed it, but I failed. maybe because I typed this question before pressing "I understand," so it got passed on to someone else. anyway,) The question text was:

> I have a sequence of 0s and 1s in this manner:
>
> ```
> xx <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
>                     0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
> ```
>
> And I want to select the 0s and the first 1s.
>
> The results should be:
>
> ```
> ans <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
> ```
>
> What's the fastest way? in R

I clicked "close" so I could vote to close as "must demonstrate a minimal understanding," but then the audit message slapped me.

I know the criteria for an audit, but I just want to know: is this one correct? Should have I selected "Leave Open," and why? Or is it just another bad audit?

Comment: What was the question the audit asked you?

Comment: @RobertHarvey http://stackoverflow.com/q/18920849/1223693

Comment: No, no.  The *audit.*  What did the audit ask?

Comment: @RobertHarvey You mean the fail message? The usual "STOP! Look and listen" one

Comment: "Should this question be closed as ...." ?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ah, it said "primarily opinion based," but I wanted to close for a different reason anyway so I clicked Close.

Comment: Worth noting: according to the timeline for the question, it never attracted a close vote, and there are no downvotes on the question.  The other reviewer chose "Leave Open."

Comment: I'm sure I'd fail.  Or skip it.  I don't really know R.

Comment: @RobertHarvey _"no downvotes"_ -- it's not so anymore (["human factor" was brought into it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773))

Comment: Guideline: "Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)" This question doesn't show any of that and should indeed be downvoted and closed.

Comment: @gnat: Pretty sure that the upvotes weren't the result of bots.

Comment: @RobertHarvey so what?

Comment: @gnat: So 7 people thought the question was good enough to upvote it, and none of the 139 who viewed it felt the need to vote to close or flag.  Are you saying they're all wrong?

Comment: @RobertHarvey how many of these 7 / 139 thought it was _also_ good for [meta-tag:review-audits]? _"Test items in review queues that are designed to help new reviewers hone their moderation skills, while nudging more experienced users that don't seem to be paying close attention to what they're reviewing."_ Are you saying all of them thought so?

Comment: @gnat: It's not reasonable to expect voters to consider how their vote might affect some obscure algorithm in the SE software.

Comment: @RobertHarvey my point exactly

Comment: @gnat: If there's a problem with the algorithm, say so.  But don't claim that the preponderance of users viewing that question are misguided.  It's their community too.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I said just that - _"human factor" was brought into it_ (into an algorithm, to fix a problem in it)

Comment: @gnat: Er... what problem, exactly?

Comment: @RobertHarvey the problem is, I recently reviewed lots of audit item candidates that were much _much_ better than this one (as a diamond you can check my self-deleted comments in answers [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196949/165773)). Compared to really good ones, slippery items like one discussed here only jeopardize idea of audits. I think these would better be filtered out to stop screwing up reviewers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While it's true that the vast majority of questions that I close under "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem," or "Problems with code must include a description of code that reproduces the problem and a description of the problem," those are *not the real reasons why I actually close such questions.*

Questions looking for code, or questions looking for a solution to a problem, aren't the real difficulties we have with the front page of SO.  Rather, it's the vague, under-specified, unanswerable questions with atrocious spelling and grammar, copy/pastes of homework assignments, and so forth.  The Eternal September, in other words.  The new close reasons work so well because those questions are almost always absent the elements that we now require.

Here's the catch.  Occasionally, someone posts a question who clearly understands what he is doing, states the problem clearly and succinctly, and asks a question that is definitively answerable and not an obvious duplicate.  It's not a highly-obscure problem, nor is it something that requires a lengthy explanation to answer.  But the OP has not posted his half-assed, broken code with the question.

Why would we close such questions?  Isn't the point of Stack Overflow to serve as a repository for problems and solutions that are broadly applicable to programmers?  Isn't it true that these kinds of questions, even though they might violate the letter of the law, certainly don't violate its spirit?  Aren't these the kinds of questions that we want to see here?  The kind that will attract genuinely good answers instead of attempting to fix broken code?

The question you have to ask yourself when you encounter a question like this during an audit, is this: *Does the question actively harm the site if it remains here?*  I think the answer in this particular audit is clear.

Comment: Ah, thanks very much for the clarification. I initially disagreed with the whole "embrace the non-Googlers" thing, but now I see your point.

Comment: Isn't this a plain and simple "gimme dah codez" question?  Aren't those always off topic?

Comment: @AdamRackis I guess not.. unfortunately it seems as though many questions are like that - from what I have seen lately anyways..

Comment: @AdamRackis: Have a look at my `icanhazcodez` question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11660127

Comment: @Robert - you'll be happy to know I had already upvoted that question :)

Comment: @Doorknob: In any case, that the audit asked you if the question should be closed as "Primarily Opinion-Based," was a clue that something was amiss.

Comment: I'm looking forward to a user actually stating (un-ironically), "gimme dah codez."

Comment: @Jamal: Nobody's actually said that in a question to my knowledge, but they have said "you can email the codes to my.email@address".

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I hate that, too.  *Clearly* an indication that the user has not the basic idea what this website is for.  It's like we're seen as a code hotline or something.