# Review Audit Fail - closed question served as known good in reopen queue

Tags: bug, closed-questions, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

The review audit pulled a total fail today.  As in a "Go home, Review Audit, you're appallingly drunk" fail.

The [subject question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/243309/how-to-find-original-source-code-of-javascript-implementation-code) (*Progs 10k+ only link*) <del>remains closed, and</del> was closed by a Programmers' mod and has been deleted by the community<sup>2</sup>.  There was even a [M.P.SE question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6697/why-are-you-moderators-so-strict) asking why the question was closed.  Another mod and yours truly explained why the question was off-topic and there was no hope of salvaging it.<sup>1</sup>

So imagine my surprise when I saw that question in the [reopen review queue](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/66359) today.  My morning coffee had kicked in, and the up vote count on the question seemed suspicious, so I clicked to open the question in a new tab.  I saw that the question was indeed still closed; realized it was an audit; and then I selected the correct action of "Leave Closed."

And I failed the audit.  Or more accurately, review audit failed to audit properly.  :-)

> [image: Horrific Fail by the Review Audit]

And just in case anyone doubts I clicked the right button in my caffeine deprived coma, I **did** select "Leave Closed."

> [image: See! The coffee had kicked in!]

Can we either

- Schedule the Review Audit for some counseling so it doesn't do this again

or

- Encourage it to share whatever it's drinking when it fails like that

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The MP.SE question is also heavily down voted due to the initial inflammatory rhetoric the OP used in asking their question.  The OP was asked to clean up their language and has since edited / removed the rhetoric.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Specifically, 3 community members voted to delete the post and it was removed on June 21st.  Beyond reference material for this question, there really wasn't any need to have kept the question around.</sub>

---

Oops! Review Audit did it again.  This time, it bit another user [in close queue](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/close/74382) and yet another user [in reopen queue](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/74478). FWIW question used in these audits not only was closed, but also [failed to reopen](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/74195).

Checking the timestamps, the question had been closed a few days prior to the audit.  Does this suggest that the review audit is using a cached list of questions? And perhaps the cache needs to be refreshed more often?

Comment: The review queue wouldn't fail this way if people stopped upvoting these fscking posts.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The review queue *shouldn't* fail this way, upvotes or no upvotes. If the actual post is currently closed, and you click "Leave Closed", *that should not fail an audit*.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - Part of the problem may be that the post received several up votes and then sat for a bit (few days) before being noticed.

Comment: same failure yet again in close queue - question closed about 3 days before is shown as known good in close queue, WTF - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/review/close/74382 ...

Comment: ...something is broken, not only because these audits violate rule ["No close votes or downvotes, ever... for close/reopen audits"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168372/165773) but because these are bad (not clear cut) for _any_ kind of audits, no matter known good or bad, and no matter what queue. No sensible [selection algorithm](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196949/165773) could pick these for audits

Comment: looking at vote split, views and answers in these funny "audits", it feels as if a new goal has been introduced lately: to teach reviewers leave open [any garbage that manages to get into hot list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237391/165773 "see 'At smaller sites, penalize hot questions having 3-4 close votes'") (both questions in broken audits look like have been listed there)

Comment: ...regarding caching, I wouldn't be sure to blame it. More likely is that [little elves just fly too slowly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268460/why-does-the-review-audit-take-longer-to-load-than-a-normal-review#comment76762_268460) :)