# Yet another feature request to prevent off-topic questions be marked as HNQ

Tags: feature-request, tags, off-topic, hot-questions

Recently one questions on Web Applications (WA) reached the HNQ. This was tagged `dns` by the OP.

The WA's `dns` tag excerpt currently says (emphasis mine)

> Domain Name System - Usually questons(sic) about DNS are not questions for end-users of web applications, so **they are off-topic for this site**.

The WA's tag wiki content currently is

> Other sites in the Stack Exchange network that you could check for
>   questions about Domain Name System (DNS) are:
>
> - https://serverfault.com
> - https://superuser.com
> - https://webmasters.stackexchange.com
>
> For further help about where to ask a question about DNS, go to
>   https://meta.stackexchange.com

Please avoid that questions tagged with "don't use" / "off-topic for this site" be shown as "hot network questions" specially on small sites that are almost "drama-free" (I'm OK with having some *on-topic* drama on my beloved WA)

In order that the above happen I think that the ♦ moderators / CM should be able to mark some tags to be exclude questions from be included on HNQ.

---

What is happening?

- The self-answered question that triggered this request was posted
- Apparently it was shared on the wild and it attracted bonus association users who upvoted the question.
- In a few hours it was marked as HNQ
- The question was migrated to another site
- The migration was rejected
- Those who voted to close the question can't vote to close it again.

  - This is "a problem" because "small sites" have very few user that participate on reviewing questions

In the mean time there are several questions on Meta about the off-topic questions, there was an issue withe the migration-rejection causing that the question were marked as deleted after the migration rejection .

Personally, I'm waiting for ♦ moderators to close the question as off-topic.

Related

- [At smaller sites, penalize hot questions having 3-4 close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237391/289691)
- [Remove question from HNQ if it has close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272230/289691)

Comment: I don't understand, if the question was off-topic, why not just close it?

Comment: @BelovedFool Automating things that can be automated lets humans devote more time to more interesting issues.

Comment: @BelovedFool Sometimes the closing as off-topic a question take some time and a drama dosis . I think drama related to off-topic HNQ on small sites sometimes is too much drama and will refrain even more the meta participation

Comment: All questions tagged *dns* are off topic there? If so, maybe you could follow in M&TV's footsteps where identification questions became off topic - the tags are still there, but you can't tag a question with them.

Comment: Yet another downvote for unnecessary features.

Comment: @AnneDaunted I didn't found yet a DNS question that could have only the DNS tag that is on-topic on WA. IMHO the DNS tag is a meta-tag on WA.

Comment: @AnneDaunted what is " M&TV's footsteps"?

Comment: @Rubén [movies.se]

Comment: Moderators have the capability to remove questions from the HNQ.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought on an **alternative solution**, but I'm not sure if including it on the question will make it too broad, so I'm adding it here.

> Slowdown the HNQ tagger on small sites, in other words, don't mark as HNQ questions newer than 3 days or if their migration were reject in the last 3 days.