# failing review audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I've just had a [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/3841713) and failed it. I wanted to downvote it and then comment, since I had seen that exact question awhile ago, and the answer I had to review was mentioning the exact same approach as what I clearly remembered as the top answer, if not top answers, except it was way less complete than the answer I clearly remembered. I wanted to downvote it for lack of originality (using the same tactic as all the other answers) and I wanted to comment explaining that. I also made sure to check the timestamp, and it said 10 minutes ago.

I'd like to know, is it bad if you don't pass an audit? Also, has anyone else ever been in a situation like this at all?

Comment: Normally I wouldn't downvote an answer for being less substantial than another answer unless it had so little substance that it didn't answer the question, and in the case of that specific answer, I do believe it does answer the question.

Comment: @BenLee My second question most certainly isn't answered in that question.

Comment: You mean your second question, "Has anyone else ever been in a situation like this at all?". Maybe clarify what you mean there, because to me it seems like that question answers it.

Comment: @BenLee the question is if anyone has been in a situation like mine where they failed a review because of a similar situation like the one I described.

Comment: Failed audit too, but in other direction :)   1) I do not agree with very low quality question, that has been used for audit. 2) Every time I downvote I feels that I doing something bad, because SO downvote me. So, I decided to not to review anymore.

Comment: You mean you want to know if I ever "wanted to downvote and then comment since I vaguely remember seeing something before and the answer reminded me of the same approach I clearly remember except it was less complete and I wanted to downvote for a lack of originality because it used the same approach as other answers"? No, I don't think that has ever happened to me before. Have I had bad review audit experience? [Yes, I have](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195983/172661). Have I failed a review for those specific reasons? No.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, good job being aware of the problem of late answers that add nothing to those already available. That's not something a lot of folks bother to check for, but they should. Second, good memory!

Next time though, be a bit more diligent about verifying the problem before voting; after all, it's not like there aren't duplicate or near-duplicate questions - it takes only a few seconds to pop open the full question and verify that the answer you *thought* was there actually is. In this case, it didn't matter - but if it hadn't been an audit, you might've left a very perplexing vote and comment.