# Bad Audit Question

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

So I just failed an Audit question (first time ever, AFAIK) because I voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400772/code-interface-to-work-with-database-operations).

The Failed-Audit message told me that I should not have voted to close because "this question does not have any problems", but honestly, this question has a *lot* of problems.  Oddly, it was asking me if it should be closed as "Too Broad", but although I wanted to give a different reason it never asked me, it just said "Audit Failed ...".

Rather I'd have said that it's biggest problem is that "It's unclear whats being asked here.", because it has a couple of hundred lines of text, almost as much code (plus diagrams), with four (4) major edits appended in pretty much random order using self-referential subject assumptions that are impossible to track down because its so large and disorganized.  There *may* be a good question buried in there, but *right now* it's in serious need of extensive editing before that could be said.

So, how do we get this fixed?  (The bad Audit question, not the specfic question itself).

Comment: Simple: we riot.

Comment: Track down the 5 people who upvoted it and send them to a Reeducation Center?

Comment: Related: [Failed a Reopen Question audit — sure looks like “Not a real question” to me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168366/failed-a-reopen-question-audit-sure-looks-like-not-a-real-question-to-me) While the question asks about reopen audits, the question and accepted answer seem to apply equally to close audits.

Comment: Queue Meta effect.

Comment: @apsillers Yes, I saw that one and that's why I posted this here. (or did I misunderstand the answer?)

Comment: **Closed** 1 min ago :)

Comment: @RBarryYoung If you saw that, then why post this question?  It's basically an exact dupe.  It's shown as an audit because it meets all of those criteria.  You alone can trivially make it not meet those criteria though a single close/down vote.  Voila, the post is now no longer an audit.

Comment: @Servy  I'm trying to get a bad audit question removed.  The answer there said that the way to do that was to "..post them here", which is what I did.  If I misunderstood the answer (possible) then I'll be happy to rectify it.

Comment: @RBarryYoung To get it removed as an audit you need to do more than make sure it doesn't meet the given criteria.  A downvote is by far the most effective way of doing that.  I'm not sure if Shog actually wants everyone posting every bad audit they find just so they can keep track of how the system is working.  I'd hope not.

Comment: @Servy I'm just going by what the answer said. I don't spend a lot of time over here in Meta, but I was convinced to post by Shog's answer and the fact that there was a `[disputed-audit-reviews]` tag, so I figured that this must be the practice. (though now I see that it only has 1 subscriber ..)

Comment: @RBarryYoung I wouldn't look into the number of subscribers too much. Meta doesn't exactly get a lot of traffic (compared to SO) so most question make it to the front page (and sit there for a while).

Comment: Seems like a good place to flog [my suggestion to handle bad audits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/191262#191262) - essentially, let us dispute bad audits automatically.