# Reopen audits choosing borderline cases?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, review-audits

Recently, the reopen queue audit system presented me with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260598/css-framework-for-creating-complex-math-expressions).

I voted to leave closed and was surprised to see I had failed.

I'm not writing here to complain about having failed, I was really curious if this question does not fall into "primarily opinion based" or maybe even "recommend a tool" as reasons for closing.

This is not a rant, I'm serious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the criteria for choosing an audit:

> Right now, these audit questions are selected using the following
>   criteria:
>
> - Recently asked
> - Score between 5 and 15 (inclusive)
> - Never locked, migrated, or deleted
> - No close votes or downvotes, ever
> - (On Stack Overflow) at least 100 views

(taken from [Shog's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168372/180276))

In his answer, he also discusses the reasons why these conditions are not exactly optimal; they sometimes choose questions that should indeed be closed. Such as this one.

Unfortunately, there's not much you can really do about it other than posting here on meta like you just did. It's just one audit failure; just ignore it and continue as normal.

I have cast the first closevote. It also appears that someone has downvoted it, although that wasn't me.

Comment: *Sure*, it wasn't you... :-) Then again, the way people have been coming after downvoters with pitchforks lately, I can't blame you.

Comment: @Cody Why would I downvote? It's not a bad question :P And I haven't been seeing any of the angry users with pitchforks lately, maybe only in certain tags?