# Reopen audit question selection

Tags: support, review, review-audits

The criteria for selecting reopen audit questions as defined by [Shog here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168366/failed-a-reopen-question-audit-sure-looks-like-not-a-real-question-to-me/168372#168372)

- Recently asked
- Score between 5 and 15 (inclusive)
- Never locked, migrated, or deleted
- No close votes or downvotes, ever
- (On Stack Overflow) at least 100 views

The above criteria show that audit questions will only contain the post for Re-Open criteria. How will the system detect if a user is clicking continuously `Re-Open` without reading posts?

Comment: Reopen queue audits exist.

Comment: @Oded - Do you mean there are audits where bad, closed (or deleted) questions are used for audits and clicking on `Reopen` will fail the audit and clicking on `Leave closed` will pass the audit?

Comment: @hims056 - I don't know the details. Just that audits are enabled on this queue.

Comment: @hims056 yes!!! we need to audit in all possible ways. we need to stop click click click for reopen too

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed - I think it's already there but not sure about it. We also require for Edit button too..

Comment: @Oded audit enabled, but need to check audit question selection.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different sorts of audits that you'll encounter in both the Close and Reopen queues: known-good (the criteria you found) and known-bad. In the reopen queue, continually clicking "reopen" will get you past a known-good audit, but immediately fail when you encounter a known-bad audit. The reverse is true for the close queue.