# I disagree with that audit - low effort convert-that-for-me-question

Tags: support, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I've just 'failed' an audit in close queue for that question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061359/how-to-convert-a-for-loop-to-a-while-loop-in-java

I think that it should be closed as off-topic (no effort). Even if for some reasons it need not to be closed, such borderline questions should never be chosen for audit.

Yesterday I've 'failed' that audit: [Is this an acceptable way to create a lock in Java ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130678/is-this-an-acceptable-way-to-create-a-lock-in-java) and now I'm blocked.

I've thought someone is chosing such malignant questions for some reason, but [according to that answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168372/155074) they are blindly chosen by the algorith. In that case please just review that audits and check for similar issues and in the future, think of auditing the audits itself. Please remove also that audits from my audits history. If you disagree and think those are good audits, write the reasons as the answer.

Comment: What do you actually want to hear? Is an unban request why you are asking?

Comment: @JanDvorak I request to remove that questions (and the questions of that type) from review audits. Controversial questions should not be used as audits.

Comment: Yeah, that first question is fluffing terrible, but apparently 5 of our peers don't agree.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I think they've wanted to earn easy rep on that question, and upvoted to encourage the OP to repay with upvote on their answer.