# Audit failed, and now unsure about my judgment

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I received [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4106690) in the first post review queue, and was about to vote to close as

> **Off-topic:** Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or
>   favorite off-site resource [...]

I failed the audit, and I'm now not entirely sure if I have understood the close reason correctly. Am I misinterpreting this question as asking for a tool or library, or is this a "borderline" or invalid audit test?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a bad audit. There were three close votes for that off-topic reason that had previously expired on that question. It just didn't get enough attention.

Comment: I thought it was promised that question that had a close vote or close flag would **never** be a good-quality audit. Should I start a new question about that case or just existing answers to existing questions should be updated? Example [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168372/155074)