# Failed Audit : 4118533 - Close Votes Review Queue

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, close-reasons, disputed-review-audits

This seems too broad and/or off topic (for finding a tool). https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4118533 So I clicked close, but I got this :

> [image]

Am I right that this question should be closed? Or if I'm wrong, why is this question acceptable?

Comment: Yeah, I'd say this question should be closed... I just VTC.

Comment: With no idea what to start from, it sounds too broad

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're right, that question should be closed. It's not clear what it's asking for, but if it's not asking for a library recommendation, it should be closed anyway for just being unclear.

Comment: I have made some edits to try to make that more clear. But I cannot give more information. My problem was that a wanted to split an MP3 file using NODE. I cannot give more information, it was my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I encounter such reviews sometimes, too. This is one of the rare cases where the audit system selects a post as audit because it doesn't match any of the system's close criteria.

Shog has posted [some requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168372/195761) for audits used in the reopen queue. I assume that this requirements fit for audits that expect the user to click <kbd>Leave Opened</kbd> as well.

I don't worry about such review fails. I just open the question itself and vote to close. That ensures that this question will never be used as a review again: So one failed audit on my record, but problem solved for all other users.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian Remember that by casting a close vote the post gets added to the close votes queue and will be closed once enough reviewers have visited. Posting it here on meta will get the question closed quickly, but what would happen if for all about 120k questions that are in the close votes queue a meta thread would be opened?

Answer (score -13):

This question is short, but on topic.  Your close vote is incorrect.

It

- has enough information to diagnose the problem
- demonstrates a minimal understanding of the problem being solved, although this could be expanded
- is scoped to a specific problem in a specific language (it's not too broad)

While general recommendations for "a tool, library or favorite off-site resource" are off-topic, this question is not asking "what's your favorite Node.js MP3 splitter?" - it's just asking for *any* solution to a specific problem.

Additionally:

- A specific, correct answer to this question is imaginable (and possible)
- This correct answer would be helpful to future visitors

That said, it could be improved by editing. I'd:

- change "proccess" to "process"
- remove "Thanks!"
- change "fine" to "find"
- Leave a comment asking the OP to expand on any attempts they've made so far, if any

But demonstrating prior failed attempts is *nice-to-have*, not *need-to-have*.

Because the question is salvageable through minor editing, and focused enough to have a good answer that's helpful to others in the future, it shouldn't be closed.

Comment: *Any* solution to a specific problem is pretty much the definition of "too broad" with a hint of "tool request" on top. How can you state it contains enough information to diagnose the problem/demonstrates understanding if there is no information whatsoever?

Comment: Following the logic you've posted, the question "I want to write a file system driver for Linux in Visual Basic 6. I've searched everywhere for a library that will let me do this, but can't find one. How can I do that?" is a valid question that shouldn't be closed. There's enough information to identify the problem, it has a minimal understanding (it's clearly understood a driver is needed for Linux file systems), and it's scoped to a specific problem in a specific language (VB6). Should it be left open as well as long as I add enough relevant tags (vb6, file-systems, a couple more)?

Comment: It doesn't contain "no information whatsoever". It contains a specific language, a specific framework being used, a specific operation that needs to be performed, and a specific file format,  Writing a file system driver is a substantially broader topic than splitting an MP3 using JavaScript and Jquery
.

Comment: Yes. Obviously I'm in the minority here. My direct language (“X is Y” vs. “I think X is probably Y”) was incorrect. I do understand your argument, but I still think someone answering a question like this is likely to provide helpful information not only to the OP, but to future people who want to modify MP3s in JavaScript. My intuition is that this particular question with the OP's particular constraints could be answered concisely and specifically. These types of disagreements are why we vote to close. I'll admit the question would likely be closed, but I would not close 
it

Comment: @AaronBrager this kind of questions probably fits more in [SoftwareRecs.SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) as I see all the answers discuss different modules. Granted, it's still in beta though.

Comment: The proliferation of knowledge to other SEs I don't count as a good thing. I'd prefer programming knowledge stay on SO where I only need a single search engine.

Comment: @Xorlev my search engine of choice is Google... it does a pretty good job of finding SO posts, generally ranking them on top. I don't know for certain if it will find relevant material on other SE sites though (I've not seen that happen yet).