# Don't include posts in known good when a plurality of reviews on the post recommend deletion

Tags: feature-request, review-audits, low-quality-posts

Take for example, [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7466717) which failed with a 'recommend deletion' for something that wasn't an answer:

> I'm a developer at Spotify. We know that there are some regressions in the new client, especially regarding remote control. I'll ask my colleagues about this issue, also can you please confirm that this problem is on Windows?

Previously, this post had been in the [low quality review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7414181) and received 5x recommend deletion reviews and 3x looks good (which completed the review before a 6th could be done). Setting aside the "why didn't anyone go back to down vote it?" which would have removed it from the looks good candidate set...

Don't include any posts where there has been a low quality review where the plurality of votes on it was "recommend deletion".  Doesn't matter if it was edited, or if it was up voted or down voted... just don't include these posts as "known good" because clearly they aren't.

Relevant MSO post: [Why did I fail this review audit when the post is clearly a comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288699/289086)

Comment: worth noting that single downvote may even be not enough to kick it off the LQ audits - [this would be guaranteed only for close/reopen ones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168372/165773): "No close votes or downvotes, ever (*only* for close/reopen audits)"