# What action should I select when happening upon a reopen vote audit?

Tags: support, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen, review-audits

On Stack Overflow's *Reopen Votes* review, it sometimes checks if we're still paying attention. When I open the actual question, it shows that it isn't closed.

And the options I get in the review queue are something like <kbd>Leave Closed</kbd>, <kbd>Edit and Reopen</kbd>, <kbd>Reopen</kbd> and <kbd>Skip</kbd>.

Actually the first three options can not be used in such a scenario. So should I go for skip or what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that this is a timing issue: when the system selects a question for the reopening review, it is still closed, but only one vote short of being reopened.

By the time you get to evaluate the question, someone else could have given that question the last reopen vote. The page is not dynamic enough to react and let you know that the question no longer requires your attention.

When you see something like that happen, simply skip to the next question.

Comment: Yeah, that may be the reason. And I meet this scene everyday for 3-4 times. :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya That may be because of a relatively small size of the reopen queue: everybody is looking at the same question at the same time, and you need only five to reopen.

Comment: The system (also?) selects questions that have never been closed as "obvious" reopen candidates. [That's part of the confusion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167239/how-do-we-select-audits-for-reopen-review).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly (which was a real challenge by the way), you're referring to situations when the system gives you false questions that should remain closed, and asks you what to do with them.

These are called **[audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)**, they test your attention. Answer them correctly as you would with any other question. If you fail too many of these, you'll be suspended from reviewing for several days.

Comment: I got suspended many times and **for 2 days** only.

Comment: But in that case which option should i go with? "Skip" ?

Comment: You should evaluate the question normally, and decide whether it should be reopened or kept closed. The system already knows the answer, it's just checking to see if you're paying attention.

Comment: Yes I agree. I pay attention and find that that **question is already open** and I have to choose from "Leave Close", "Edit and Reopen", "Reopen" and "Skip".

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: You vote on what you would have done if it were a real question. Disregard the fact that it's already open, the question is made up by the system.