# Dispute reopen review audit

Tags: discussion, support, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2910181). The original post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521895/http-connections-while-ios-app-is-in-background-and-retrying-if-offline). I don't think this audit is good, because the question is clearly "too broad" and should be closed as such, and remain closed as such.

No harm is done, but I know that the posts that get put into audits are automated, here is a case where the automated process failed.

**edit:**

I also just failed [another audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2910388) ([original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383381/eclipse-menus-disabled-on-os-x-10-9-beta-6)). Clearly this should be closed as off-topic because it is about "general computing hardware and software".

I think there are probably a few problems with the reopen audits. Until they are fixed I am going to stop reviewing in that queue - because I fear the auto-ban might get me.

**The point of my post** (as it seems unclear to some):

I think these specific audits are on bad posts, and I think they should be removed from the selection of audits for this queue.

Comment: What is the question - whether we agree?

Comment: @JanDvorak I added clarification.

Comment: What you ask for is not possible technically, unless the system will be changed to pick audits manually. Those audits are already "used" and as far as I can tell, won't appear to anyone else any more.

Comment: if bad audits should be removed (which pretty much everyone agrees), please suggest an automated way to detect (at least some) bad audits

Comment: How about instead of removing bad ones - try to filter them out of getting into the selection process to begin with?

Comment: @InbarRose the same issue: suggest how

Comment: There have already been a few suggestions in various posts, they don't belong in this post. I suppose the purpose of this post is to just notify about 2 specific cases where the automated process failed (in my opinion). But if it leads to a solution that would be great - But I do not know enough about the SO system to be of any real help. My favorite suggestion so far was here... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167239/how-do-we-select-audits-for-reopen-review?lq=1 - the **disagree** button!

Comment: @Lance how is that a dup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with you on the [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2910181).  It seems to me to be way too broad as well since it is someone just asking for hints on how to develop something.  I think it is an interesting question, but it is not a fit for SO.

I don't necessarily agree with you on [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2910388). Yes it is about software, but it is about Eclipse, so I believe it fits under the this provision in the on-topic question list.

> - software tools commonly used by programmers

Now, I do not think this is a well asked question by any stretch as it is just saying "I opened Eclipse and couldn't do anything" and a screenshot to prove the menus are gray, but I don't think it is as clearly off topic as you say.

The criteria for selecting reopen audit questions as defined by [Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168372/182513) are

> - Recently asked
> - Score between 5 and 15 (inclusive)
> - Never locked, migrated, or deleted
> - No close votes or downvotes, ever
> - (On Stack Overflow) at least 100 views

So by simply using your own privileges, you have the power to remove what you perceive a bad audit question from the queue by casting a downvote or a close vote.

Since you asked this question, the first post has picked up 2 close votes, so it will no longer be used as an audit question.  The 2nd post <s>still meets the criteria as it has not picked up and downvotes or close votes</s> has picked up a downvote, so it will no longer be used as a reopen audit either.