# Question about review ban and frequency of audits

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits

About a week ago I got a two day ban from reviewing (I understand and accept that), after getting unbanned I was more careful with the reviews. Since then I only failed one review (about an hour ago), and I have now been banned for seven days. I can understand the reason for audits and banning if too many are failed, but isn't that a bit on the heavy side (getting a seven day ban after failing one audit in four/five days). I am new at reviewing, so it might just be me?

My other question (in relation to the audits), in the last day I have gotten ~10/11 audits. On [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167962/how-many-failed-audits-to-be-put-on-quarantine) answer it says:

> Ok - so the logic is supposed to give you an audit every 20 reviews or so; it looks at reviews in any queue though. .... We're tweaking the logic here: 5% chance of being audited starting 5 reviews after your last audit.

A few of those audits I got were nearly one after another. Why have I gotten so many or is the information in that answer outdated?

Comment: 93 Reviews, 0 failed. No, it's not hard. Audits are chosen for being easy. Frequency, I have found, is all over the place.

Comment: I didn't say they were hard...

Comment: If it helps, this is the audit that you failed, which I believe is what triggered the latest ban: http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/4348513 . That wasn't an answer, it was a follow-on question and "No Action Needed" was not an appropriate response to that. The system might be a little more strict with audit failures in the Late Answers queue, because bad reviews there can let spam and non-answers slip through. I would rather have the system err on the strict side for that particular queue, especially after having to ban 5 reviewers recently who approved multiple instances of spam.

Comment: I had miss read the answer (skipped over one or two of the words) and thought it was an answer (I'll know to be more careful next time). I can understand it being more strict, but banning after one failed review (in 4/5 days)...I guess I'll just wait a week and try harder not to fail any more audits.