# Inline code overlaps link underline

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks, inline-code

When inline code appears directly below a link, it overlaps and hides the underline of the link (on Meta, the only visual indicator that a link is present. Example on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164770/167443):

> [image]

I see this on IE 9.

Not sure if this happens on sites other than Meta.

Comment: It happens in many other [cases](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114109) and [ways](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161235) too.

Comment: @animuson once I noticed it, I have realized that it **happens freaking everywhere.**

Comment: Not for me on Chrome. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/38516275/MyWebPage/Questions%20on%20when%20to%20flag%20-%20Meta%20Stack%20Overflow.png

Comment: @DJDavid98 now that you mention it, this specific instance doesn't overlap for me, either. [Is this part of the new slimmer UX?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158762/188613)

Comment: These issues are dependent upon your browser and/or font settings. Different browsers, fonts, etc will cause different line heights and other small differences that aren't very noticeable on the large scale but are for tiny things such as this.

Comment: @animuson I'd like an 'official' verdict on this. If it is indeed browser/setting dependent, I'd like to how to stop this from happening, because it's [annoying as hell](http://xkcd.com/1015/).