# Best way to handle suggested edits to accepted answers

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, accepted-answer

I recently was presented with this edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4003993

In general, what's the feeling on allowing an edit of an accepted answer, and one that has so many upvotes?  Should it have been a comment to the answer rather than an edit to the answer?  With that many upvotes, and with the code unproven, I don't know if I feel confident in accepting the edit.

The community's guidance is appreciated.

Comment: The reviewers got it right.  Look at the reason each one of the rejectors selected.

Comment: Well that one I'd definitely reject, it should be a comment if anything.

Answer (score 3):

> In general

Screw "in general". Evaluate the edit on its merits, in the context of the post being edited. If you don't know enough about the subject to be able to tell whether it's good or bad, *skip it*. If it made sense to reject edits based on [simple rules like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153241/was-this-a-valid-edit-that-i-should-have-approved/153279#153279), we could just do that automatically and skip the whole "reviewer" bit. In fact, we already *do* that, so if you're even seeing an edit there's at least a slim chance there's some worth to it.

The only edits you should evaluate consistently regardless of content or context are [the fake ones generated for audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159544/why-no-honeypot-suggested-edits/165489#165489) - they're crap 100% of the time or your money back.

P.S. Comments are often hidden, deleted or unread. Posting any non-trivial amount of *code* in comments is just cruelty to the reader. Don't put anything of value in comments if you can avoid it, and don't encourage others to do so either.

Comment: It sounds like you're actually advocating using (not just edits, but suggested) edits to maintain someone else's code in an answer.  You do realize this is a controversial subject, right?  And that the community consensus is far from clear?  This is why we have a general principle of moderation that users should not need to know anything about the subject matter in order to effectively moderate.

Comment: Sure - we've been arguing about this for years, @Robert. And as much as I *personally* believe you should make whatever edits are necessary to improve the post without deviating from its *spirit*, I recognize that this is often not cut and dried - which is why I emphasize evaluating each edit in the context in which it was made. Slapping down all but the most banal edits kills a great deal of utility in exchange for allowing brain-dead reviewing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You do realize that Shog carefully didn't weigh in on one side or the other? Presumably with the intent that we'd both agree with his consensual position, but in fact you find his answer makes him a rabid encourager of content defacement and that I find that his answer makes a rabid opponent of collaborative improvement.

Comment: @Gilles: I trust that Shog9 is sufficiently capable of articulating that himself.  And for the record, I don't bite other people, so being rabid has no relevance here.

Comment: @Shog9: I would love to believe that you can treat Stack Overflow as sort of a poor man's Github.  Unfortunately, I haven't seen this work out well in practice; most efforts that I've seen at editing code are pretty poor, and I prefer that users point out in comments problems with code that I've posted, so that I can fix it myself.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Most efforts I've seen at editing code are either obviously wrong and rejected (or very rarely they're done by users with the edit privilege, but it's a lot rarer than correct edits), or welcome and (if suggested edit on SO then rejected else accepted). This includes edits by me, edits to my posts, and cases where I'm a bystander.

Comment: @Gilles: I would prefer that someone actually weighed in and decided, one way or another.  I'm tired of hearing arguments about it.  While I'd prefer that people let me maintain my own code in my own answers (I see it as a gesture of politeness and respect), I'd have no problem with it if they could do it in a way that respected my original intent.  The CC:Wiki license (and "other people may edit your posts") notwithstanding, there's still some concept of post ownership by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the answer is accepted and highly upvoted is irrelevant.

In the words of the [official guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/editing):

> When should I edit posts?
>
> (…)  Common reasons for edits include: (…)
>
> - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages

This edit is a minor change to the post; it respects the core logic and leaves most of the details intact, and purportedly correctly handles a case that the original case did not handle correctly. It is intended to correct a minor mistake in the original code.

So it boils down to: does this edit indeed **correct a minor mistake**?

- If it is correct, accept the edit.
- If it is incorrect, reject the edit.
- If it is not quite right but on the right track, improve the edit.
- If you aren't sure, for example because you lack the requisite subject knowledge, skip the edit.

A [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) would not be appropriate to correct a mistake in an answer. Comments are only for **temporary** notes. For example, “X is wrong but I don't know how to fix it” should be posted as a comment, and stay until someone comes along and makes the required fix. On the other hand, “this is wrong and here's the precise way to fix it” should not be posted as a comment, it should be an edit that implements the fix.

Comment: This isn't a minor edit.  It is making a significant change where there is no basis for assuming that the author's original intent was to include this content.  In contrast to what you have quoted, you seem to be asserting that any edit, regardless of how major, or what it changes, should be made so long as you feel it is correct.  That is false.  Major changes to the post should not be made through edits regardless of who thinks they are correct.

Comment: @Servy This is a minor edit. It adds three lines of code that don't change the core logic nor most of the details. You're right that major changes should not be made through edits, but this is not a major edit.

Comment: It doesn't look like a minor edit to me.  Code edits are already controversial anyway; if someone wants to make one, they can wait until they have full editing privileges.

Answer (score -1):

Edits are there to improve the presentation of the author's content, not to change it.  Their goal is to make the reader better comprehend whatever it was that the author was trying to say.

If you would like to add entirely new content then the appropriate medium to do so is either through a comment to the answer, or if you are providing enough content that you feel it is worthwhile, an entirely new answer to the question.  (Just be sure that if posting a new answer, it fully answers the question, and that it's not just a reply to another answer.)

The rejection of the edit was correct, and for the correct reason.

That the answer is accepted has no bearing on this decision.

If a post is marked as Community Wiki, though, that changes matters entirely.  The whole point of marking a post as CW is to say, "This post is no longer just mine.  Anyone and everyone is free to change the *content* of the post, not just its presentation."  If the post is marked as CW and there is a suggested edit that changes its content, then approve/reject the suggestion based on whether it is correct, and whether it improves the quality of the post.  It is under no obligation to maintain the authors intent.

Comment: That whole Community Wiki idea is something that I haven't seen articulated on Meta before.  I'll have to think about that.  My initial instinct is to say that CW already lowers the bar enough, and that we don't need another "bifurcation" in the rules (Suggested editors are already treated differently from normal editors: suggested edits must be "substantial," for one thing)

Comment: Please read the [rules on editing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/editing). Correcting minor mistakes are a valid and encouraged reason to edit. I have no idea whether the code modified by this edit is correct; if it is, the edit should be accepted.

Comment: @Gilles This *isn't* correcting some minor mistake.  It's not just a small change that the author clearly intended to write.  It is adding entirely new content to which there is no indication at all that the author *intended* to be there.

Comment: @Servy Conversely, there is no indication at all that the author didn't intend it to be there. Maybe it's a boundary case that he didn't think of but would have included if he had. If you want posts that other people can't edit, you're in the wrong place.

Comment: @Gilles This isn't Wikipedia.  While it does incorporate some elements of it.  Answers *are* owned by their author, and they *are* intended to maintain that author's intent.  You are *not* free to make any edit that you want, on any post, in which you change as much as you want.  If you feel that an answer is incorrect and has major problems the solution is to write your own answer, not to edit an existing answer that is quite different.

Comment: @Gilles `"Conversely, there is no indication at all that the author didn't intend it to be there."` That's irrelevant.  If you plan to edit content into a post you are obligated to demonstrate that the author *did* intend it to be there.  I am not obligated to show that he doesn't want it to be there to reject the edit.