# Should I be seeing an edit button for other users while logged in to stackexchange?

Tags: bug, mobile-web, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can any user edit any other user’s question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120576/why-can-any-user-edit-any-other-users-question-or-answer)

I am logged in to stackexchange using chrome mobile and it looks like I can edit other users posts. There is an edit button instead of a comment button, and clicking it allowed me to view the editing screen for that post. I did not edit because I did not want to change the content of the question, but it seemed as if I could.

I also did not see a comment button. Is this a big on mobile chrome, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

As explained [in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120576/why-can-any-user-edit-any-other-users-question-or-answer), any user can edit any other user's post (even anonymous users can do that). Under the 2,000 reputation threshold, this requires peer review before it takes effect, but the process is otherwise the same.

You cannot comment because you haven't reached the 50-reputation threshold required to post comments, which is why you see an edit link, but not a comment link.

Comment: I don't think that you must have 50 reputation to comment. The reputation required to [comment everywhere](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) is 1 reputation. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @PicrofoEGY: That's only on Meta...

Comment: You are right! Thank you for clarifying this :)